# divide parallel arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer-division, parallel-arrays

I have a question about dividing parallel arrays. I'm fairly new to C++. In my program I'm dividing parallel arrays (atBats[] and hits[], and storing the results in an empty array (batAvg[]. When I divide, the new array remains blank even though the other two arrays are holding correct data. I just need to know why the batAvg array is not updating to store the new data.

```
int main() {

    //declare variables and arrays
    const int SIZE = 20;
    int playerNum[SIZE],
        atBats[SIZE],
        hits[SIZE],
        runs[SIZE],
        rbis[SIZE];
    double batAvg[SIZE];
    int numberPlayers;

    //Load number of players from the loadArrays method
    numberPlayers = loadArrays(playerNum, atBats, hits, runs, rbis);
    batAverage(atBats, hits, batAvg, numberPlayers);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}//end main

int loadArrays(int playerNum[], int atBats[], int hits[], int runs[], int rbis[]) {

    //Define variables
    int i = 0;

    //Open file and read arrays
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("BaseballStats.txt");

    //Let user know if the file fails to open
    if (inputFile.fail())
        cout << "There was an error opening the file.\n";

    //Load the arrays from the file and increment count each loop
    while (inputFile >> playerNum[i]) {

        inputFile >> atBats[i];
        inputFile >> hits[i];
        inputFile >> runs[i];
        inputFile >> rbis[i];

        i++;

    }//end while loop

    //Close file and return count as reference to the number of players
    inputFile.close();

    return i;

}//end loadArrays method
```

Everything is fine up to this point, but the batAverage function is where the batAvg array is not storing data correctly. The array reads all zeros, even though it should be storing numbers such as 694, 417, 389, and 488.

```
void batAverage(int atBats[], int hits[], double batAvg[], int numberPlayers) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberPlayers; i++) {

        batAvg[i] = (hits[i] / atBats[i]) * 1000;

    }//end for loop

}//end batAverage method
```

This is the data from the file I am reading into the program:

10 36 25 2 5
2 12 5 0 1
34 18 7 1 0
63 41 20 4 2
12 10 3 1 0
14 2 1 1 1
27 55 27 10 8
8 27 12 3 4
42 32 8 2 1
33 19 4 1 0

Comment: Are you aware that when you write `batAvg[i] = (hits[i] / atBats[i]) * 1000;`, that `hits[i]` and `atBats[i]` are integers and the result is an integer? Try `batAvg[i] = hits[i] * 1000. / atBats[i];` instead. (don't forget the dot after 1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 batAvg[i] = (hits[i] / atBats[i]) * 1000;
```

inside the parenthesis, both numbers are integers, so the expression is an integer. So if hits[i] < atBats[i] the result is zero, which then you multiply by 1000.

Try this instead:

```
 batAvg[i] = (1000.0 * hits[i]) / atBats[i];
```

EDITED: 1000.0 instead of 1000 since the required result is a double.

Comment: Still does integer division. Since `batAvg[i]` is a `double` I would recommend putting a dot after the `1000`.

Comment: @nwp Yes but there is no harm here, because the result will be stored in an integer anyway. EDIT: oops sorry, you are right, I will edit.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you're not passing the parameter `double batAvg[]` by reference. Try:

```
void batAverage(int atBats[], int hits[], double& batAvg[], int numberPlayers)
```

Edit: I'm stupid and A.S.H should be right

Comment: No, this is not the problem here. `double batAvg[]` works just like `double *batAvg`.

Comment: I didn't know that, in my college we would use vector<double> batAvg. Thanks! Then A.S.H is right.

Comment: And `std::vector` is usually the way to go! Don't worry about posting wrong answers if it does not happen too often (although you should be confident that you are right of course). It still happens to me too. In this case (the answer is wrong and does not add anything useful to the accepted one) you might consider deleting your answer.